# WTForms getting the errors

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

Currently in WTForms to access errors you have to loop through field errors like so:

```
for error in form.username.errors:
        print error
```

Since I'm building a rest application which uses no form views, I'm forced to check through all form fields in order to find where the error lies.

Is there a way I could do something like:

```
for fieldName, errorMessage in form.errors:
        ...do something
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The actual `form` object has an [`errors`](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/forms.html#wtforms.form.Form.errors) attribute that contains the field names and their errors in a dictionary.  So you could do:

```
for fieldName, errorMessages in form.errors.items():
    for err in errorMessages:
        # do something with your errorMessages for fieldName
```

Answer (score 41):

A cleaner solution for Flask templates:

Python 3:

```
{% for field, errors in form.errors.items() %}
<div class="alert alert-error">
    {{ form[field].label }}: {{ ', '.join(errors) }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Python 2:

```
{% for field, errors in form.errors.iteritems() %}
<div class="alert alert-error">
    {{ form[field].label }}: {{ ', '.join(errors) }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is the best effort on this page. But it looks like somebody took a crap on my form. Exposes the form names too, for my end-users to figure out what cli_tel actually is... Though I might be the only one that cares?

Comment: @PeterLada: that's the stupid thing... the errors variable doesn't really provide that. You can do it with something like this I think: `form[field].name`

Comment: If you use python3, use `items()` instead of `iteritems()`

Comment: instead of using just `label`.  Use `label.text`.  ie: `flash(''.join([f'{form[f].label.text}: {"".join(e)} ' for f, e in form.errors.items()]))`.  Removes the html.

Answer (score 23):

For anyone looking to do this in Flask templates:

```
{% for field in form.errors %}
{% for error in form.errors[field] %}
    <div class="alert alert-error">
        <strong>Error!</strong> {{error}}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

With `ModelFormFields` in `SqlAlchemy` when used with `WTForms`, if you have a nested object inside an object (foreign key relationships), here is how you show the relevant errors for fields properly.

Python side:

```
def flash_errors(form):
    for field, errors in form.errors.items():
        if type(form[field]) == ModelFormField:
            for error, lines in errors.iteritems():
                description = "\n".join(lines)
                flash(u"Error in the %s field - %s" % (
                    #getattr(form, field).label.text + " " + error,
                    form[field][error].label.text,
                    description
                ))
        else:
            for error, lines in errors.iteritems():
                description = "\n".join(lines)
                flash(u"Error in the %s field - %s" % (
                    #getattr(form, field).label.text + " " + error,
                    form[field].label.text,
                    description
                ))
```

Jinja side:

```
  {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
    {% for message in messages %}
      {% if "Error" not in message[1]: %}
        <div class="alert alert-info">
          <strong>Success! </strong> {{ message[1] }}
        </div>
      {% endif %}

      {% if "Error" in message[1]: %}
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
         {{ message[1] }}
        </div>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endwith %}
```

Hope that helps.