# Flask wtforms ValidationError not displayed to user

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm using flask wtforms with input validation. Everything's working fine, except with validation failure my ValidationError message is not getting displayed to the user...

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, PasswordField, ValidationError # URLField, EmailField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email, EqualTo

class SignupForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField("Name:", validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField("Email:", validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField("Password:", validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('pass_confirm', message='Passwords must match')])
    pass_confirm = PasswordField("Confirm:", validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Create Account")

    def validate_email(self, field):
        if User.query.filter_by(email=field.data).first():
            raise ValidationError('Your email has already been registered.')

    def validate_name(self, field):
        if User.query.filter_by(name=field.data).first():
            raise ValidationError('This username is taken.')
```

and in my view:

```
@users.route('/signup', methods=['GET','POST'])
def signup():
    form = SignupForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        url = form.name.data # todo: generate unique url
        user = User(name=form.name.data,
                    url=url,
                    email = form.email.data,
                    password = form.password.data)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()

        return redirect(url_for('users.login'))

    return render_template('signup.html', form=form)
```

and this is the template:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Sign up Page</h1>
  <p>Please fill out the form</p>
  <form method="POST">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ form.name.label(class='form-group') }}
      {{ form.name(class='form-control') }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      {{ form.email.label(class='form-group') }}
      {{ form.email(class='form-control') }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      {{ form.password.label(class='form-group') }}
      {{ form.password(class='form-control') }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      {{ form.pass_confirm.label(class='form-group') }}
      {{ form.pass_confirm(class='form-control') }}
    </div>

      {{ form.submit(class='btn btn-primary') }}
  </form>

</div>
```

Upon submitting an invalid form (either invalid email or name) the form simply returns blank, without indicating what the user did wrong. How can I display those validationerrors to the user? Much appreciated!

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20644520/5378816

Comment: that solves, it - thanks so much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. But the moderators will probably close your question as a duplicate.

Comment: that's fine - better to have only one question with many votes than duplicates. Do I need to upvote our answer? plus can I give you the bounty somehow?

Comment: I don't think I deserve a bounty for writng a short comment. Don't worry, enjoy SO.

Answer (score 0):

form must get some data

```
@users.route('/signup', methods=['GET','POST'])
def signup():
    form = SignupForm(request.form)
```

or

```
@users.route('/signup', methods=['GET','POST'])
def signup():
    form = SignupForm(request.json)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for contributing, @xiaoqiao! This didn't solve my problem, unfortunately... The form still comes back blank after the user entered invalid input.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are importing ValidationError incorrectly
Try this importing it from wtforms.validators like this->

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, PasswordField # URLField, EmailField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email, EqualTo, ValidationError
```

In addition to this, you can add flash messages to your screen from your routes code such as this.

```
from flask import flash
if form.validate_on_submit():
    flash(f'Info was saved to the database for user {form.name.data}', success)
else:
    flash('Failed to save to database', 'danger')
```

Comment: Thanks for checking, Andrew. Unfortunately it's still now showing validation errors... I'll let you know if I figure out what's going wrong. Hehe, I guess I'll be answering one question a day for a long time to get back where I was ;)

Comment: If a view function flashes some messages, the template must render them: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/flashing/

Comment: @Muriel if you're still stuck on this, can you share all of the code? I feel like I can help w/ the solution if I could run it locally myself